# Searching for a robust Linux FTP server with short string response codes

Tags: linux, ftp

We are huge fans vsftpd and have been using it for years because of it's robustness.

We are; however, coming into issues with costs. Many of our environments that we work in are at the "ends of the earth", so to speak, and we can only communicate either via Cellular or Satellite connections.

Cellular costs at these locations are $1.00/MB on average and up to $26.00/MB for Satellite connections. So every byte we can save counts.

With that being said, the strings that are included in the responses from VSFTPD are very useful for troubleshooting but become very costly in an environment such as ours with thousands of active ftp sessions per day.

I have researched and can not find a way to turn off these response strings without going into the source and editing the code within VSFTPD.

I do not feel that I am familiar enough with the "nitty gritty" of the FTP protocol to know what is absolutely required for the program to run correctly. Therefore I am hesitant to edit the source code for VSFTPD.

Are there any linux based ftp servers that are robust but with a mode for minimal responses?

For instance, this is what I see now:

```
Status: Connecting to 66.xx.x.x:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 Welcome to BLAHBLAHBLAH FTP service.
Command:    USER ftpuser
Response:   331 Please specify the password.
Command:    PASS *******
Response:   230 Login successful.
Command:    SYST
Response:   215 UNIX Type: L8
Command:    FEAT
Response:   211-Features:
Response:    EPRT
Response:    EPSV
Response:    MDTM
Response:    PASV
Response:    REST STREAM
Response:    SIZE
Response:    TVFS
Response:    UTF8
Response:   211 End
Command:    OPTS UTF8 ON
Response:   200 Always in UTF8 mode.
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/"
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Switching to Binary mode.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (66,xx,x,x,129,120).
Command:    LIST
Response:   150 Here comes the directory listing.
Response:   226 Directory send OK.
Status: Directory listing successful
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    CWD DLT-CONFIG
Response:   250 Directory successfully changed.
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/DLT-CONFIG"
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (66,11,7,2,66,146).
Command:    LIST
Response:   150 Here comes the directory listing.
Response:   226 Directory send OK.
Status: Calculating timezone offset of server...
Command:    MDTM L99999-CONFIG.TXT
Response:   213 20130129145139
Status: Timezone offsets: Server: 0 seconds. Local: -18000 seconds. Difference: -18000 seconds.
Status: Directory listing successful
```

We would like to see something more like this if possible:

```
Status: Connecting to 66.xx.x.x:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220
Command:    USER ftpuser
Response:   331
Command:    PASS *******
Response:   230
Command:    SYST
Response:   215
Command:    FEAT
Response:   211-Features:
Response:    EPRT
Response:    EPSV
Response:    MDTM
Response:    PASV
Response:    REST STREAM
Response:    SIZE
Response:    TVFS
Response:    UTF8
Response:   211
Command:    OPTS UTF8 ON
Response:   200
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200
Command:    PASV
Response:   227
Command:    LIST
Response:   150
Response:   226
Status: Directory listing successful
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    CWD DLT-CONFIG
Response:   250
Command:    PWD
Response:   257
Command:    PASV
Response:   227
Command:    LIST
Response:   150
Response:   226
Status: Calculating timezone offset of server...
Command:    MDTM L99999-CONFIG.TXT
Response:   213
Status: Timezone offsets: Server: 0 seconds. Local: -18000 seconds. Difference: -18000 seconds.
Status: Directory listing successful
```

Thank you for your time and I look forward to your answers.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend gadmin-proftp. Highly customizable and can be configured with custom certs. You can probably modify it to your needs via their GUI. They may not offer a minimal response mode but to some extent that could be achieved presumably.

Comment: I'll check it out

Comment: I checked it out and I was able to configure my own language file to remove all the unnecessary language. It still has the full responses though. I think the full text is necessary for the ftp protocol. I'm not sure though. I'm going to talk to the client and see what they are currently using. I bet this is just something that they are hoping for and they don't have a clue.

Comment: A lot of the response messages are necessary and yeah I would go to clients next in terms of what they are requesting of the server. You may be able to reduce the traffic from that end.